# Meaning of $\gamma=0+$ notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Here $v$ is continuous at $(0,\rho)$ and $v$ is smooth $\forall \rho$, $\gamma \neq 0$

what is the meaning of $\gamma=0+$ in the following context:

If $v(\gamma=0+, \rho)=v(\gamma=0-,\rho)$ $\implies$

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial \rho}(0+,\rho)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial \rho}(0-,\rho)$

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v(\gamma = 0+, \rho)$ means $\lim_{\gamma \to 0+} v(\gamma, \rho)$, i.e. the limit of $v(\gamma, \rho)$ as $\gamma$ approaches $0$ from the right.

Comment: Great, however I do not follow why if  $v(\gamma=0+, \rho)=v(\gamma=0-,\rho)$ $\implies$



$\frac{\partial v}{\partial \rho}(0+,\rho)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial \rho}(0-,\rho)$

Comment: This claim is not true in general, because derivative and limit operations do not commute.  Perhaps some addditional assumptions have been made that make it true.  Some more context might help.

Comment: v is continuous at (0,ρ) and v is smooth ∀ρ,  ∀γ st γ≠0

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  This is not sufficient to make $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial \rho}$ have limits as $\gamma \to 0+$ or $\gamma \to 0-$, or to make those limits equal when they do exist.  For example, take $v(\gamma, \rho) = \gamma \arctan(\rho/\gamma)$ for $\gamma > 0$, $0$ for $\gamma \le 0$.  Then $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial \rho}(0+,0) = 1$ while $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial \rho}(0-,0) = \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial \rho}(0-,0) = 0$.

Comment: The context relating to this has been added to the OP. Apologies if I have provided too much, I just want to be sure I haven't missed anything.